# Create button formatting in android

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I will have many buttons of the same size.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a standard button formatting with a set

- height
- weight
- padding
- etc.

I have looked into styles but I am not sure if that is the road I should be taking. I also thought about extending the button class and programmatically setting these values to a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello, how are you!

The best way is to create a style in the style.xml resource, all the necessary features.

just add the style with style = "@style/mystyle" to all the buttons.

**example:**

```
<style name="mystyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

In the same way when you want to create a customized button (java/kotlin)
it will also be added in the same way.

Greetings.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable component in a separate .xml file and use it everywhere since you said the dimensions exactly the same all across the app. Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
<!--customize and animate stuff-->
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#88b823"
        android:startColor="#b0dc54" />

</shape>
```